# public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ApplicationServices", throwIfV1Schema:false) equivelence in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Not quite sure how to implement this C# line in VB.NET

```cs
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ApplicationServices", throwIfV1Schema:false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a class like this :

```
Public Class ApplicationDbContext
    Inherits IdentityDbContext(Of ApplicationUser)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("ApplicationServices", throwIfV1Schema:=False)
    End Sub

End Class
```